# Youtube iframe API no-cookies GDPR compliance

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, data-protection

There's a few subjects on this already but none seem to give a definitive answer to the problem I am faced with. I am implementing youtube videos on a website using the youtube iframe api with the following code :

```
this.player = new YT.Player($player, {
    wmode: 'transparent',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
    playerVars: {
        wmode: 'transparent',
        showinfo: 0,
        autohide: 1,
        rel: 0
    },
    videoId: this.video_id,
    events: {
        'onReady': ()=>{

        },
    }
})
```

Videos are correctly being loaded with the www.youtube-nocookie.com domain. But cookies are still being loaded as other posts have mentioned. I am also getting the following warning in my console.

[image: errors]

On a side note. Other posts mention that the cookies are only supposed to load when the user plays the video. I however get these errors as soon as I load the page. The strange thing is that I still get the 1st error even when I'm not loading any videos, just adding the api script to my page.

So the question being : is this method compliant with GDPR practices? I am safe with this alone or do I need to go the extra mile and block the loading of the api until the user accepts the use of data collection? Why does youtube give use this so-called privacy mode if cookies are still being injected into my page?

Comment: Hi, is this method working for you with Safari too?